# Copying a worksheet and have the formula reference next cell from another worksheet

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

In workbook A we create individual sheets for each record. On this sheet we reference data from a single sheet in workbook B. When we create new sheets in workbook A the reference data is just copied from the last sheet and I'm wondering if we can make it automatically reference the next cell in workbook B?

Comment: What are you using for the references? can you show it?